# JPA 2 inherited @Id property

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

> [Especially when working with JPA v1.0, try not to use id inheritance.](http://damelines.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/jpa-best-practice-1-do-not-inherit-id-property/)

What is the difference with JPA 2? In particular, does it work better, i.e., can a `Stapler` and a `Chair` in the example have the same id when `strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY` is used? Or does it depend on JPA implementation and/or database driver?

Comment: Nothing is changed in JPA2 in this area. You *always* define your id in the root class of an inheritance tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that blog post makes a whole lot of sense.

I'm not even sure it is possible to not defined the Id in a superclass, unless it is a @MappedSuperclass.

It seems to be worried about running out of Ids.  If you could run out of Ids with n subclasses, then you will also run out with one class, just take you n times as much time, which is not much longer.  But running out of ids is not a problem as long as you use a long not and int.

A int id will last you about 100 years at one insert per second.  Still not "soon", but for higher throughputs possible to run out.

A long will last you about 300 million years at one per millisecond.  Not very "soon".

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Running_Out_of_Numbers

Comment: Agreed on not running out of `long` ids, but I am more concerned about concurrency :)